# Sampling Twice and Posteriors

Tags: bayesian, posterior, bernoulli-distribution

I have a random variable with some unknown distribution with support over $[0, 1]$. Every turn, I sample a $p_t$ from this distribution. However, I am unable to observe $p_t$ directly. Instead I observe the results of $n_t$ independent Bernoulli variables with parameter $p_t$ and see that $h_t$ (out of $n_t$) of them are $1$. I am not able to control $n_t$ but I am able to know what it is. What would be my posterior distribution for $p$ after $T$ turns?

I'm just learning about Bayesian statistics, so any help/resources would be helpful.

Comment: If you say that the random variable has an unknown distribution on $[0,1]$, is it ok for you to take the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$? That would then be the prior distribution of $p_t$.  Otherwise I would not be able to provide Baysian posterior.

Comment: Yea a uniform prior distribution over [0, 1] seems like a reasonable assumption. I have no reason to believe it is anything else

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities for interpreting your question:

1) There is a single p and you observe $h_t \stackrel{ind}{\sim} Bin(n_t, p)$ (notice that p does not have a t subscript). If you assume the conjugate beta prior, i.e. $p\sim Be(a,b)$, then your posterior is $p|h_1,\ldots,h_T \sim Be(a+\sum_{t=1}^T h_t, b+\sum_{t=1}^T (n_t-h_t))$.

2) You have a distribution for the $p_t$, i.e. there is a different one for each $t$. Then (perhaps) you have $p_t \stackrel{ind}{\sim} \pi$ where $\pi$ is some unknown distribution and the goal is to learn about the unknown distribution $\pi$ using data $h_t\stackrel{ind}{\sim} Bin(n_t,p_t)$. If you are willing to assume that $\pi$ is a beta distribution, you would then have $p_t \stackrel{ind}{\sim} Be(\alpha,\beta)$ and you are interested in the posterior $p(\alpha,\beta|h_1,\ldots,h_T)$. The posterior in this case does not have a closed form. A reasonable improper prior is $p(\alpha,\beta) \propto (\alpha+\beta)^{-5/2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going for the second interpretation. What would the unclosed form in this case be? Additionally, are there nice closed forms for estimators of the n-th moment of the distribution $\pi$?